# Self employed, putting away tax money

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, state-income-tax, income-tax-refund

I am starting to get behind on taxes for my business and in an effort to catch up I'm putting profit towards the taxes. Where can I store it other than my bank? I'm worried I will spend the money, I heard somewhere I can begin adding money to a taxes account to apply towards my taxes at the end of the year. Any tips, or ideas?

Also I have employers out of state, Boston and Atlanta.

Comment: If you are getting behind on taxes then either you are not actually making the profit you think you are making, or you are taking money out of the business that you shouldn't be taking out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Hearing somewhere" is a level or two worse than "my friend told me."

You need to do some planning to forecast your full year income and tax bill. In general, you should be filing a quarterly form and tax payment. You'll still reconcile the year with an April filing, but if you are looking to save up to pay a huge bill next year, you are looking at the potential of a penalty for under-withholding.

The instructions and payment coupons are [available at the IRS site](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f1040es.pdf).

At this point I'm required to offer the following advice - If you are making enough money that this even concerns you, you should consider starting to save for the future. A Solo-401(k) or IRA, or both. Read more on these two accounts and ask separate questions, if you'd like.

Comment: not to mention that three states may be involved in this tax year.

Comment: You just did. Good point.

Comment: Okay how can I go about filing quarterly I am only 17.

Comment: I added a link to the IRS document offering instructions and payment coupons.

Comment: @AustinSweat you're a minor, and you need your parents to help you with this.

Comment: My parents aren't very well educated.

Comment: This is my first year filing. I'm not sure what to do really.

Comment: The forms I linked. Go to page 8. Ignore line 7 for now, just answer the questions on that sheet. The entire exercise is you estimating your 2015 tax return in advance, and starting to send in partial tax payments.

Comment: Re underpayment penalties, as long as the total payments for a year are equal to the total tax for the previous year (which if I understood correctly were zero for the OP), then there should be no penalty.  At least that's the way I've always done it, since my income is irregular & unpredictable, and the IRS worksheets just don't work for me.

Comment: That's my problem. I'm a freelancer and have managed to land a lot of contracts recently for large jobs but I'm confused by this all.

Comment: I made nothing last year, this is the first year I won't be claimed as a dependent. I want to begin saving as well but I am becoming overwhelmed.

Comment: @jamesqf - good point if no income last year. Although, it really means that OP has 7 months to understand this, in anticipation of 2016, and he's back to calculating his 2015 tax bill if only to set the money aside.

Comment: Okay so for 2016 I need to do the estimate ? And for this year I should pay the lump sum or ? I'm a independent, doing business under my name.

Comment: As james pointed out, you can do the lump sum with your 2015 return, but will need to learn this, and file quarterly in 2016. You have time to take a breath, read, and read some more. It seems overwhelming at first, but it's not too tough.

Comment: Awesome so I should be good this year, what a relief. :)

Comment: You would probably do better just to make a rough guess, and send them that as quarterly estimated tax payments, so you aren't faced with having to come up with a big lump sum next April.  Also don't forget that you will have to pay Social Security (use form f1040sse), and probably a Schedule C - there should be a lot of expenses you can deduct from your gross income.